# C++ method defined in .h called in .cpp is not recognized

Tags: qt

I am trying to use a method called getName() that is defined in the addPlayer.h file below. The getname() method will be used in the constructor called Player. The error that I get is: 'getName' was not declared in this scope'. How can I fix it?

Thanks for helping.

The addPlayer.h file:

```
#include "../Source/Player.h"

class addPlayer : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    addPlayer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~addPlayer();

    tp::Player* makePlayer();
    void addPlayer();

    QString getName() const;

inline QString addPlayer::getName() const
{
    return (ui.name_lineEdit->text());
}
```

The addPlayer.cpp file:

```
#include "addPlayer.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

using namespace tp;

addPlayer::addPlayer(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui.ok_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,
                    SLOT(validatePlayer()));
    QObject::connect(ui.dateNaissance_pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,
                        SLOT(getDate()));
}

addPlayer::~addPlayer()
{

}

Player* makePlayer()
{
    return new Player(getName().toStdString());
}
```

The constructor is as follows:

```
class Player: public HumanBeing {
public:

    //Constructor
    Player(const std::string& p_name);

Player::Player(const std::string& p_name): m_name(p_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't properly scoped your definition of `makePlayer` -- you need to prefix `addPlayer::`:

```
Player* addPlayer::makePlayer()
{
    return new Player(getName().toStdString());
}
```

Comment: Ok that was it. Thank you RA.